# how to access to Battery Level in BroadCast Receiver using service for give me the result in kill?

Tags: android, service, broadcast

please, some help I want to get a result of battery level if **battery level = 40%** or **battery level =60%** and send it always to database using service?
another problem that is battery level doesn't auto increment .. it starts when the charger is connected just one time

[this is the service class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90VNW.png)

[this the Broadcast Receiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcIwu.png)

[and this the manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btUpz.png)